# Add default filter in view - Odoo

Tags: python, xml, view, filtering, odoo

I have created a view and defined my filter as follows:

```
<record id="dept_search_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">employee.search.view</field>
     <field name="model">employee</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="dept_search">
            <filter string="Department" name="dept_search" domain="[('e_dept', 'in', ['HR','Audit'])]">

            </filter>

        </search>
    </field>
</record>
```

Then i created the one to display the employee details:

```
 <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_employee_tree">
        <field name="name">employee.tree</field>
        <field name="model">employee</field>
       <field name="context">{"search_default_dept_search":1}</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="8" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Employee">
                <field name="e_dept"/>
                <field name="employee_id"/>
                <field name="employee_name"/>
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Even though i upgrade my application, the filter i specified as `<field name="context">{"search_default_dept_search":1}</field>` is not applied on the view.

I want that default filter to be applied and I want that this filter can never be removed in the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the same code to the ACTION that calls the view, not to the view, so just add:

```
<field name="context">{"search_default_dept_search":1}</field>
```

to the xml action.